# JQuery retrieving a value from a SharePoint list

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, caml

Afternoon all [SharePoint Currency Exchange List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4EXl.png)

I've inherited a JavaScript file. What I'm trying to do is to when a user picks a currency from a drop down menu on a SharePoint list, then inputs an amount in a second field it converts and updates in a third field.

I've got the file to show an alert for the selected currency and for the amount and now the next step is that I want an alert to show the Currency Exchange to prove that it's getting it.

This is the line I'm struggling with:

```
var ExchangeRate = ($(obj).attr("Exchange_x0020_Rate"));
```

A screen grab of the Exchange Rate list is attached and the code it below, any help would be appreciated!

```
<script src = "/sites/it/SiteAssets/scripts/sputility.js" type = "text/javascript"> </script>

<script type = "text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {});

function PreSaveAction() {
    var ExchangeRate
    var CurrencySelected = $("select[title='Currency']").val();
    var ContractCurrencyValue = $("input[title='Actual Amount in Currency ']").val();

    alert(CurrencySelected);
    alert(ContractCurrencyValue);

    $().sputility({
        operation: "Getlistitems",
        listName: "Currency Exchange Rates",
        async: false,
        CAMLQuery: "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value  
        Type = 'Text' > " + CurrencySelected  + " < /Value></Eq > < /Where></Query > ",
        CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef  
        Name = 'Exchange_x0020_Rate' / > < /ViewFields>",
        completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
            $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
                var ExchangeRate = ($(obj).attr("Exchange_x0020_Rate"));
                //var CurrencyValue = ExchangeRate*ContractCurrencyValue;
            });
        }
    });
    alert(ExchangeRate);
    alert(CurrencyValue);
}
  </script>
```

Comment: I think its syntax error, try this            var ExchangeRate = ($(obj).attr("ows_Exchange_x0020_Rate"));

Comment: Cheers, I tried that and I'm still not getting an alert for the Exchange Rate?

Comment: Whats the request status? Use something like Chrome network tab to see the requests error message and status code. It could be you caml query btw, i think closing tags should not have space between < and /.

Comment: Hi Alex. How would I find that out on IE? Also those spaces aren't in the original code, they seemed to have just been added...

Comment: Actually looking at it, I'm getting an error on the Debugger which says: "X -Object doesn't support property or method 'sputility"

Comment: A slight development, when I remove SPUtility -  ({
        
        //SPUtility.GetSPField: 'GetListItems';
        //var ExchangeRate = SPUtility.GetSPField('Currency Exchange Rates');
        operation:"Getlistitems",
        listName: "Currency Exchange Rates",    I get a third alert but it's coming back undefined?

Comment: Check the response, whether it has any error,                  
    `completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
            alert(xData.responseText);
            $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
                ExchangeRate = ($(obj).attr("ows_Exchange_x0020_Rate"));
                alert("ExchangeRate: "+ExchangeRate);
            });
        }`

Comment: It alerts: ExchangeRate: undefined. Could it be the name of the list and file? It's a separate list with the address when sorted by exchange rate of: http://collaboration-dev.norgine.com/sites/it/Tools/IT-Contracts/Lists/CurrencyExchangeRates/AllItems.aspx?View={8070b6ff-2fd2-4af6-8eb4-74152b266516}&SortField=Exchange_x0020_Rate&SortDir=Desc&InitialTabId=Ribbon%2EListItem&VisibilityContext=WSSTabPersistence

Comment: Actually I think it may because I'm not referencing SPservices in the file but I am using the APIs later  (operation:"Getlistitems",) could that be it?

Comment: first of all refer SP services, then alert response,   
  `alert(xData.responseText);`  &  check whether there is any error

Comment: Check this [**Link**](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/crud-operation-on-list-in-sharepoint-using-jquery-and-spservices) for sample for SP services operations

Comment: I've added a link to the source js library in the header <script src="//xxxJS/jquery.SPServices-2014.01.min.js"> and now when I save the item in the debugger I'm getting 'The attached target document mode 8. Some console APIs and features may not be available.'